# This is about the Exception Handling and the Exception Matching Concept in Java

Tags: java, exception

I am new to Java. I was going through the Exception Handling Concept but I stuck at one point here.
We know that whenever the Exception is thrown Java will try to find by looking at the available catch clauses in the top down manner. If it doesn't find one, it will search for a handler for a supertype of the Exception.If it does not find a catch clause that matches a supertype for the exception, then the exception is propagated down the call stack.

Also if most specific exceptions is placed above the more general exceptions handler then it results in the COmpilation error.

Suppose we have a code as shown below:-

```
try{
    // do not know what kind of exception it will be throwing but I am sure that it is IOException
   }

try{
     // Here the FileNotFoundException is thrown
   }

catch(IOException e){
//Do exception handling stuff
}

catch(FileNotFoundException f){
  //Do exception handling stuff`
 }
```

Now this code will result in the compilation error because the Supertype of the exception is present above the actual exception.

SO why the first paragraph do not support this concept. i.e After checking JVM will found the appropriate exception(FileNotFoundException) and should not bother about IOException clause, but run into compilation error instead.

Please throw some light on it.
Also let me know If I am able to explain what I want to??

Comment: This code does not compile, because `try` following another `try` block is illegal syntax. But why should a 'first paragraph' that you wrote support anything except what is in your head? Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: have you tried to write above provided code snippet in IDE.

Comment: Guys, please read more carefully - the OP *is* aware that the code does not compile!!! It *is* a good question related to the SO standards. Our community should be more tolerant to the beginners. The OP tried to implement the exception handling how he understands it, it doesn't work and he is asking us what he did wrong. Why the hell should anyone downvote such a question, just because it is under Their Master Level?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are misunderstanding the try concept.  You only have one try followed by the catch clauses.

```
try{
    // do not know what kind of exception it will be throwing but I am sure that it is IOException
   // Here the FileNotFoundException is thrown
}

catch(IOException e){
    //Do exception handling stuff
}

catch(FileNotFoundException f){
  //Do exception handling stuff`
 }
```

Comment: He has *two* `try` clauses, placed illegally.

Comment: @EJP: I think Mike Murphy is addressing exactly the issue of two `try`s! And he *is* (at least partially) answering the OP's question.

Comment: I am not talking about the programming.I am just taking an example that suppose we have two try clauses anywhere within the program and have catch to handle those exception.

Comment: Generally JVM looks for the actual catch clause,but it is not found then it searches for the super class of that exception class.
But the point is we have it here,so why does it throw the compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

This code will throw an error at compile time because for FileNotFound Catch Block the code will be unreachable as it's already handled by IO Exception and FileNotFound is subclass for IOException

**Unreachable catch block for FileNotFoundException. It is already handled by the catch block for IOException**

FileNotFoundException is a subclass of IOException gives us the choice of either treating all IOExceptions the same, or catch some of IOExceptions subclasses individually

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet has fundamental mistakes

If an exception occurs within the try block, that exception is handled by an exception handler associated with it. To associate an exception handler with a try block, you must put a catch block after it

Recommended reading:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html